# Is there any way to refresh the ng2-konva layer?

Tags: angular, konvajs, konva

I have created an angular component which is responsible to draw the images on the web screen,
I created two konva layers, baseLayer and assetLayer. BaseLayer will draw base image on screen and than assetLayer will draw another setup of images on base image.

Each base image has there own number of assets to plot on base image. But Only first base image is plotting the assets and then if i change the next slide it's not changes the assets on the base image.Things which i tried are given on documentation of ng2-konva http://rafaelescala.com/ng2-konva/  librarary. But still not working.

**Issue which I am facing is assetLayer is not refreshing when I change the slide**

I am sharing my stackblitz url to see the working example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2konvademo?devtoolsheight=33&embed=1&file=src/app/components/views/floor-view/floor-view.component.ts

See in console we are getting number of assets on each slide, those should be rander on base image.

Comment: There is an issue with your stackblitz link "Error in /~/src/app/app.module.ts (27:17) konva is not defined". In general, in native JS, after you change the stage contents, you would call stage.draw(). In the examples on the ng2-conva page search for .draw() and you will see it in use. Maybe you can add that to achieve what you need ?

Comment: Should be noted that ng2-Konva looks like it may not be supported - no changes to code on Github for at least 2 years. Happy to be corrected.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat issue in stackblitz has resolved, you can see the running code now.

Also I tried that draw method also. but it's not working.
this.stage.getStage().draw();